# Is decorators in python example of monkey patching technique?

Tags: python, monkeypatching

Recently I was reading about monkey patching technique and wondered if it can be said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Decorator = a function that takes a function as an argument and returns a function

Monkey patching = replacing a value of a field on an object with a different value (not necessarly functions)

In case of functions monkey patching can be performed via a decorator. So I guess decorator might be thought as an example of monkey patching. However commonly monkey patching refers to altering behaviour of a 3rd party library. In that case decorators are less useful.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose on some grammatical level they may be equivalent. However, decorators are applied at the time a function or class is defined, and monkeypatching modifies an object at runtime, making them very different both in spirit and in actual use.

Comment: In Python decorators are applied in runtime. Functions/classes are also "defined" in runtime. Actually everything, even syntax checks is in runtime.

Comment: @Bryan If you say monkey patching "modifies an object" then decorators also modifies functions and function are objects in python. So this can be said right ?

Comment: @soupboy: decorators don't modify a function, they take a function as an argument and then return a different function. The original function is  unchanged. From the programmers perspective it's more-or-less the same as if the original function was modified, which is why I said they could be considered the same "on some grammatical level".

Comment: Ok @BryanOakley got it.